# TeamCity Rake runner incompatible with test-unit 2.0.0.0?

Tags: ruby, rake, teamcity

I'm attempting to setup a build configuration for a simple Ruby project. I downloaded and installed Ruby 2.0.0.0 via the installer package:

```
C:\Users\misztalm>gem list
```

**LOCAL GEMS**

```
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

I'm attempting to configure a Rake runner, but I'm getting the following error.

```
Rake runner isn't compatible with your'test-unit-2.0.0.0'(C:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\test-unit-2.0.0.0) gem. Please submit a feature request.
```

I'm unable to downgrade/delete the test-unit gem (since it's a default gem). I attempted to manually set the rake version to 0.9.6, but it didn't have any effect. Please tell me how I should make this work.

I'm using the latest TeamCity v8.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem but I was able to get it working by installing the latest test-unit gem

```
$ sudo gem install test-unit
Fetching: test-unit-2.5.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed test-unit-2.5.5
```